# Similarity between two lists of real number, where the numbers lie in the range $[0,1]$

Tags: inequality

In a code which I was reading ,the similarity score of list 1 as compared to list 2 is calculated as

List one
$[0.28, 0.17, 0.28]$

List two
$[0.09, 0.24, 0.15]$

Similarity Score =

${([0.28/(0.28+.09)] +[0.17/(0.17+0.24)] + [0.28/(0.28+0.15)])}/3$

3 is in reference to the length of the list

Can anybody tell explain to me what technique is this?
How does it convey the similarity score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number $f(x,y) = \frac{x}{x+y}$ for certain $x,y$ can be used to get an idea of their relation. Namely,
$$
f(x,y) \frac{x}{x+y} 
  \begin{cases}
   = \frac{1}{2} & \text{if } x = y \\
   > \frac{1}{2} & \text{if } x > y \\
   < \frac{1}{2} & \text{if } x < y
  \end{cases}.
$$
So if two numbers are approximately the same size, then $f(x,y)$ will be close to $\frac{1}{2}$. If you average this result over multiple comparisons you can get an idea about the general relative size between te numbers in the list. You have to be very careful though, since a perfect value of $\frac{1}{2}$ doesn't necessarily mean that all numbers are equal. It could also be true that some numbers are relatively large in one list, while other numbers are relatively large in the second list and that these cancel each other out.